# Head First C: Erratum? Pointer Syntax

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, syntax, assignment-operator

I am teaching myself C programming, using "Head First C", published by O'Reilly. (And a couple of other texts, besides.)

I got very hung-up during the book's introduction to pointers, by the example program on p.58. What threw me was a little call-out in the text, pointing to the line:

```
int *choice = contestants;
```

The call-out reads:

> “choice” is now the address of the “contestants” array.

And, as far as I can tell, that's wrong. That line assigns `*choice` to the *value* stored as the `contestants` array, is that not so?

Comment: The book is correct.  There's two things going on here.  "int *choice" is declaring an integer pointer.  The rest of it is assigning that pointer the address of 'contestants'.

Comment: If `contestants` is an array then `constestants == &contestants[0]`

Comment: @idle I think you are confusing the defintion/initialisation with the hypothetical line `*choice = contestants;`

Comment: Read the box further down labeled **POINTER DECAY**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The book is correct. Pointers work differently from variables, and * works differently in different circumstances.

To start, you probably know that a pointer is just a variable containing the address to the location in memory of another item

When we use
`int *choice`
we create a pointer to an integer, which stores the address of the integer

In this case, I'm assuming contestants is an array. We'll assume it's an array of ints

```
int contestants[5] = [0,1,2,3,4];
```

Collections, such as arrays, are always stored as a pointer to the first element. The second element is therefore `addressof_first_item + sizeof(element_stored)`.

Let's assume the address is `0x12345`, it's like this `int contestants = 0x12345`

And now we store that address in choice:
`int *choice = contestants`

In other words, it's a pointer to an integer, which happens to be the first element in the contestants array.

As a side note, we could also write it as:

```
int* choice = &contestants[0];
```

The other use case for the * operator with regards to pointers, is dereferencing. Dereferencing involves getting the value at the address pointed to by a pointer.

```
int value = *choice;
```

will give us an integer with a value of 0, because the address stored points to the first element

Comment: Thanks @Luke K. Your assumption was correct. Your answer is as clear as water. Maybe you should be writing for O'Reilly. :)

Comment: @idle You seem to have a favorite answer (maybe this one) and are satisfied with the explanation. Please consider using your special privilege to accept an answer, to indicate that you personally found the best help inside. This is specifically your opinion, quite distinct from the voting going on by the rest of the community. Luke K would probably appreciate the reputation, the other good answers come from multi-k accounts.

Comment: Multi-k, as in multi-thousand reputation on this site probably. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

<sub>*Disclaimer: I don't have access to the book / chapter right now.*</sub>

Considering `contestants` is of array type, quoting `C11`, chapter §6.3.2.1 (*emphasis mine*)

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the
>   unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an **expression that has
>   type *‘‘array of type’’* is converted to an expression with type *‘‘pointer to type’’* that points
>   to the initial element of the array object** and is not an lvalue. [...]

In your case, the array variable is used as the RHS of the assignment operator, so in that case `contestants` is the same as `&(contestants[0])`.

This is the exact same type of `int *` which is the same of the variable to be assigned (LHS).

Answer (score 1):

So you have four answers already, but none of them mention the difference between *assignment* and *initialization* syntaxes.

```
int *choice = contestants;  // initialization
```

The above is equivalent to this:

```
int *choice;                // declaration
choice = contestants;       // assignment to pointer
```

but completely different from this (which can't be done in an initialization):

```
int *choice;                // declaration
*choice = contestants;      // assignment to target (not valid unless choice is initialized)
```

The second version is incorrect as written because it tries to store the value of `contestants` at the address pointed to by `choice` -- but `choice` does not contain an address, unless you initialize it. Dereferencing a possibly-uninitialized pointer is always a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

What you maybe don't know is that the name of an array is a pointer on the first element of this array. example

```
int contestants[] = {1, 2, 3};
```

means that `&contestants[0]` has the same value as `contestants`

Answer (score 0):

This is explained earlier in the chapter, in the **BULLET POINTS** list.

> - An array variable can be used as a pointer.
> - The array variable points to the first element in the array.

And also further down in the box labeled **POINTER DECAY**:

> Because array variables are slightly different from pointer variables, you need to be careful when you assign arrays to pointers. If you assign an array to a pointer variable, then the pointer variable will only contain the address of the array.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. I'm catching up now. And I'm beginning to wonder if maybe HFC's loose, jocular style doesn't really fit me. That might explain why things like that list escape my attention.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, the book is not correct, but your reasoning is also incorrect.

Assuming `contestants` is an array of `int`, the initialisation

```
 int *choice = contestants;
```

is equivalent to

```
 int *choice = &contestants[0];
```

In other words, the value of `choice` is the address of the first element of `contestants`.    This conversion of `contestants` (the name of an array) to `&contestants[0]` (a pointer) commonly known as an "array to pointer" conversion.

However, this differs from the address of the `contestants` array, since the type is wrong.   The address of the `contestants` array is `&contestants`, which has type `int (*)[4]`  (i.e. address of an array of four int).

If you try to initialise

```
 int *choice = &contestants;
```

the result will be a compilation error (since an `int(*)[4]` cannot be implicitly converted to an `int *`).

Your reasoning

> And, as far as I can tell, that's wrong. That line assigns *choice to the value stored as the contestants array, is that not so?

is flawed, since the `contestants` does not have a stored value.  It is a set of values.

It is true that `&contestants[0]` and `&contestants` have the same value, but they also have different type.   So a comparison of `&contestant[0] == &contestants` will not compile.    However, if the values are converted to a common type, such as `(void *)(&contestants[0]) == (void *)(&contestants)`, the code will compile, and the converted values will compare equal.